# Admin/management software for Kiosk

Tags: windows, remote-access

I am facing to write Kiosk software, a kind of a billpayment (Windows/touchscreen/pinpad).

While the billpayment itself is just a desktop application an another question is raised -- how to manage kiosk PC and Windows?

Are there any ready-to-use solutions for kiosks like [SiteKiosk](http://www.sitekiosk.com/en-US/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx) but not website-oriented?

Is it good idea to use active directory and all the windows internal admin programs for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock down Windows XP for use as an internet kiosk?](http://serverfault.com/questions/18879/how-to-lock-down-windows-xp-for-use-as-an-internet-kiosk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a built-in for Windows 7. See this complete reference guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg176673%28WS.10%29.aspx?ITPID=sprblog

In former Windows versions Microsoft provided a software called SteadyState to achieve the same. As it is now built-in they discontinued SteadyState.

Comment: I'm aware of SteadyState, my primary concert is management, not just security. How to monitor the kiosks' state, how to control remotely, reboot remotely etc... Of course I can do it using bunch of tools, but one single ready-to-use solution would be better and easier to use IMHO.

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @DmitryKarpezo In this case your question is too vague. What is "to manage"? GPOs are all you need to manage. Eventlog is to monitor, remote desktop is for remote control and `shutdown` is for remote reboot. All built-in! Combinable with PowerShell. Also built-in and from the creator of the Operating System.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Run, Task Manager, and the like via GPO and make your application launch full-screen without a close/minimize button on the title bar. That should just about do it.